# SharePoint 2013 and people picker not working in custom C# aspx website

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I have a custom C# aspx page that was created to be used inside of SharePoint 2010. It uses several people-picker controls.

```
    <SharePoint:PeopleEditor id="peopleEditorRO" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" IsValid="true" AllowEmpty="false" Height="35px" Width="220px" BackColor="Transparent" AllowTypeIn="True" MultiSelect="false" ShowCreateButtonInActiveDirectoryAccountCreationMode="False" ShowEntityDisplayTextInTextBox="False" CssClass="ms-usereditor" ForeColor="#2864A5"></SharePoint:PeopleEditor>
```

It worked great in 2010. But in SharePoint 2013 when I click on the browse icon nothing pops up. So I found this:

```
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

Now when I click on the browse icon this is what appears: A white blank pop up window. And the actual people picker popup. I can keep clicking on the browse icon and it will keep adding more popups.
[image]

I must be missing some kind of reference. It obviously is not displaying correctly, Any ideas?

Even the ClientPeoplePicker doesn't display correctly:

```
    <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker runat="server" ID="PeoplePickerControlName" Required="true" ValidationEnabled="true"
                     InitialHelpText="text"
                     VisibleSuggestions="3"
                     Rows="1"
                     AllowMultipleEntities="false"
                     CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" />
```

I should add when I create a sharepoint page and add an iframe with the source being the aspx page. The 2010 people picker works. The ClientPeoplePicker still has display issues.

[image]